# How can I remove empty strings in template literals?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a script that loops through an array of objects and creates `.edn` file that we're using to migrate some of our client's data.

As we have to use `.edn` file which uses `Clojure`, I generate a template literal string and populate the data in the format that we need.

In the generated string I have many conditional operations, where I check if some data exist before returning some string. If the data doesn't exist I cannot use null, so I use an empty string. Now when my file gets created, those empty strings create an extra line that I want to remove. Investigating it more, the string adds `/n` which actually creates those extra lines from an empty string.

What is the best way to do it?

**This is an example of what I'm doing:**

```
arrayOfObjects.map(a => {
   return `
    ; ...other code that doesn't depend on data
   
    ; Code that depends on data, if it's false I want to remove it completely and
    ; and avoid passing empty string as it creates extra space in the generated file
        ${a.stripe_connected_account
            ? `[[:im.stripeAccount/id]
                #:im.stripeAccount{:stripeAccountId "${a.stripe_connected_account}"
                  :user #im/ref :user/${a.user}}]`
            : ""}   
`;
});
```

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Hey @CherryDT, thanks for the reply. So whitespace (empty string) adds /n which then adds extra line in the generated file.

Comment: I have added more information in the comment. Sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: And you were completely right, it's the new line that gets created with the empty string. So I want to only display the code if the condition is true, if it's false I either want to remove the new line generated with an empty string or don't even show the condition if it's false. (if I try to use &&, and the data isn't there it just displays undefined).

Comment: My point is - the string doesn't add anything (neither `\n`, which is something you only see as encoded output anyway, nor anything else). You add that, outside of the `${ }`, yourself. If you'd start the `${ }` expression earler and end it later and put the whitespace (if you even want it) as part of your if-true expression of the ternary, you will get what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I see what's happening now. I've managed to fix it up. If you want you can post your comment as an answer, and I can approve it. Thanks again.

Comment: Done (and removed obsolete comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty string doesn't do that. `T${''}h${''}i${''}s` is no different from `This`. The "extra space" is the whitespace that you (unconditionally) include in your template string around the `${ }` part:

[image]

If you'd start the `${ }` expression earlier and end it later and put the whitespace (if you even want it) as part of your if-true expression of the ternary, you will get what you want.

For example:

```js
arrayOfObjects.map(a => {
  return `
    ; ...other code that doesn't depend on data
   
    ; Code that depends on data, if it's false I want to remove it completely and
    ; and avoid passing empty string as it creates extra space in the generated file${
      a.stripe_connected_account ? `
    [[:im.stripeAccount/id]
    #:im.stripeAccount{:stripeAccountId "${a.stripe_connected_account}"
    :user #im/ref :user/${a.user}}]`
      : ""
  }`;
});
```

(Yes, the strange indentation is a result of merging two different indentation levels, the code's and the output's, and preventing line breaks in the output unless desired. I tried several ways to format it but none of them looked good  - there are only ugly ways, no way to indent it nicely and have the result you want, unless you were to write a tagged template function that would smartly detect when a `${ }` expression would need surrounding whitespace stripped and when it wouldn't.)